# change the AWS EKS EC2 autoscale group instance machine type?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, autoscaling

I would like to change the AWS EKS EC2 instance type by adding the new autoscaling template. I want to downgrade from 8vCPU/16GB mem to 4vCPU/8GB mem. I would like to know what will happen and if there will be any downtime when rebuilding all the running instances with the new instance type.

Is that anything need to check before apply a new launch template to the EC2 autoscaling group?

Thanks,

I created another version of EC2 auto scale group launch template with smaller machine type.